# Bind OnTextChanged Event TextBox inside Gridview inside Update Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a `GridView` containing a `TextBox` in `<asp:TemplateField />` and The `GridView` is residing inside an AJAX Update Panel.
I want to register the `TextChanged` Event for the textbox inside the GridView but only for the first row inside the Grid.

Is there a way to do it?

I tried binding the `OnTextChangedEvent` and `AutoPostBack = true` for `TextBox`, but it is firing for textbox in each row. How can I limit that `TextChanged` Event to only the `TextBox` in first row in the `GridView`.
Can you please help me.
Thanks and appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can use `GridView_RowDataBound` event and instead of attaching event to `TextBox` in aspx markup, do it via code behind:

```
protected void view_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowIndex == 0)
        {
            TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtBoxId");
            txtBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(txtBox_TextChanged);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do it like that, The postback is not happening..can you please tell any laternate solution.Thanks.

Comment: even if you set the AutoPostBack property of text box to true?

Comment: yes, fixed that by attaching the event in RowCreated event rather than RowDataBound event